# How can I hide photo "likes" on Facebook?

Tags: privacy, facebook-photos

I want to like a picture of someone else on Facebook, but I do not want friends to see that on the news feed.

Is is possible to change the settings in "who can see your future posts"? Does that also include the photo likes?

Answer (score 0):

Facebook is a social networking sites.This medium through which we can communicate through friends,and group to whom we are associated.In the Facebook whenever we "likes" any photo it will visible by everyone who is added in your friend group.To hide the photo likes by you on the Facebook,you have to just click on the hide on the timeline then the photo is visible by you only.

Comment: I am talking about photos of other people...not my own photos